# Android Live Testing

Tags: android, testing, debugging

I am making a game for android and in it I am using sensors which are not available in the emulator. At the moment I am connecting my device and transferring the apk, then installing to test but that is a pain to do, and I have gotten to the stage where I need to start logging values for debugging. I have gone into the run configs of my app and set it to prompt me to pick a device, but my device is never in the list when it is connected to my PC and I try to run it. How am I supposed to set it up to work properly?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Doesn't sound like this is specific to game development. General programming questions should be asked on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: EDIT: This works fine on it's own. It's only when I implement it into my game that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what engine you are using. Are you using a custom engine? You could easily create a method when building your apk to upload it to your phone as well.

If you are using an already made engine then its dependent on that. Unity supports building to the phone, LibGDX does as well.

What are you creating this in?

EDIT: After reading your problem again. If your phone doesn't show up in ADT. You need to make sure you have the USB drivers for your phone installed. Make sure USP debugging is on. And if it's a Nexus device change the connected mode to camera and not media.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had USB debugging on, but I had to download the OEM drivers from the Samsung website. Working well now :)